# filter in angular js returns same value

Tags: angularjs

```
 here is my custom filter for angular js

app.filter('convertedTime', function () {
return function (date) {
    dateObject=moment().utc(date).format('HH:mm');
    return dateObject;
  };
```

})

here is my view file

{{data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated |convertedTime}}

my problem is every time filter returns same value.

Comment: share data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated value and expected value from filter

Comment: can you provide html code?

Comment: You can use $filter in angularjs to format the time. 
In your controller inject the $filter and 
do like data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated = $filter('date')(data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated,'HH:mm') and in the view just bind {{data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated |convertedTime}}

Comment: Are you sure that the departureTimeEstimated returns the correct value? I've created a working plunkr, which works. http://plnkr.co/edit/kVaM2ltNkPVp17dYOSAc?p=preview

Comment: here is view code                 <div ng-repeat="data in totalObject track by $index" class="main-row">
       {{data.legs[0].origin.departureTimeEstimated |convertedTime }} 
    </div>